# Inverse of Matrices Problem

Tags: matrices, inverse

I had the equation 
$AX + B = CX$

which I rearranged to be 
X = $(C-A)^{-1}$ B

BUT I'm not quite sure how to go about solving $(C-A)^{-1}$. 
I have a rule written down in my notes that 
$(A+B)^{-1}$ is not equal to $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ 
and I'm assuming that's the same for subtraction. 
Could some one please help me out? 
Thank you!!

Comment: Notice that $AX+B=CX$ by itself is not a question. That's just an equation. ... What's your question? But yeah, I don't think $(C-A)^{-1}$ has a nice form in terms of just $A$ and $C$ and their individual inverses.

Comment: I have a matrix multiplied by X + another matrix = a third matrix multiplied by X again, and I need to solve for X. So I now my three matrices: A, B, and C. And I'm left with the equation : AX + B = CX, so I need to rearrange to get X on one side, so that I can solve for X using rules of matrices! But I'm just not sure how to rearrange it so that I can have something nice to solve. They're all 2x2 matrices. I would type out the question but the formatting isn't allowing it!

Comment: [See this tutorial on how to type mathematics on this site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: BTW, $(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1}+B^{-1} $ is wrong for any group, not only for the group of matrices. It is that same, as to assume that $\frac{1}{a+b}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$ for any non-zero numbers a and b. As about inverse matrix, your notes or textbook should tell, how to calculate it. Please, read carefully, before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no nice form in general for $(C-A)^{-1}$, but since they're just $2\times 2$ matrics, you can calculate $C-A$ by hand, and the calculate the inverse of that by hand, remembering that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
= \frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d & -b\\-c & a\end{pmatrix}
\,,$$
then multiply that result by $B$ by hand. This calculation is not too arduous.